# Doing Remote Contract Work Residing In Japan?

Tags: visa, japan

I am a Canadian who develops video games that run on a USA based game website. I plan on moving to Japan for 2 years to study Japanese as a student! I'm trying to figure out if I am allowed to continue doing my work whilst in Japan?

I develop video games for a video game portal, and if my games do well, I get paid more, and if they don't do well, I could make nothing. (So I'm not technically an employee, I am paid via PayPal as a contractor)

Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of visa would you be staying under?

Comment: @deceze A student visa

Comment: AFAIK you can work part time (some 28h/week) as a student. I'm no expert on whether there are any additional catches. Practically speaking, it'll be hard for anyone to proof how much you actually worked if you're working freelance on your own.

Comment: Since you aren't working for a Japanese company --> employed *in* Japan, then the employment restriction doesn't apply to you.